# MySQL Foreign Key Referencing WHERE field=value

Tags: mysql

I have a table created in MySQL (see the code below). As you see in the code I have a foreign key manager which references the idNo. However I only want to reference to employees with the cat='B'. So I need something like

```
FOREIGN KEY (manager ) REFERENCES Employee(idNo WHERE cat='B').
```

Any ideas how I can accomplish this.

```
idNo SMALLINT AUTO_INCREMENT UNIQUE, 
name VARCHAR(25) NOT NULL, 
telNo INT(11) NOT NULL, 
cat CHAR(1) NOT NULL, 
manager SMALLINT, 
PRIMARY KEY (idNo ),
FOREIGN KEY (manager ) REFERENCES Employee(idNo) on DELETE CASCADE)ENGINE=INNODB   
AUTO_INCREMENT=1000;
```

Answer (score 0):

Foreign keys do not allow conditions.

If you want to force the condition, you must do it via coding.

It can be done inside your non DB code (Java, PHP, VB,...), or you could create a procedure in MySQL that would be called to perform the insert and that will return an error code if condition is not matched.

If you insert from various codes/application, the procedure is the way to go since it would be centralized.

Answer (score 0):

Create a new `UNIQUE KEY` in `Employee` combining `idNo` and `cat`.

```
ALTER TABLE Employee ADD UNIQUE KEY (idNo,cat);
```

Make a foreign key in the child table that references that new unique key.

```
ALTER TABLE SomeTable ADD FOREIGN KEY (idNo,cat) REFERENCES Employee(idNo,cat);
```

Then you just need to make sure `cat` is constrained to the single value 'B' in the child table. One solution is to create a lookup table containing just the single value 'B'.

```
CREATE TABLE JustB (cat char(1) PRIMARY KEY);
ALTER TABLE SomeTable ADD FOREIGN KEY(cat) REFERENCES JustB(cat);
```

Now the only value you can use in the child table is 'B', so naturally it can only reference rows in `Employee` that have a `cat` of 'B'.

Another solution would be to use a trigger, but I favor the lookup table.